# How To use Iframe in Mobile Website in .net

Tags: .net, asp.net

Hi am new to developing Mobile Web site in .net . how can i use HTML IFrame in my Website.
and if any alternate Web Control to open other web page in my current page Please help me . Thanks in Advance ..

Comment: Add an `<iframe>` tag to your page. I'm not sure what else you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an iframe for a website targeted at mobile devices isn't recommended, as not all the mobile browsers support iframe (and to be honest, iframes are evil...)

For reference:
http://www.smashinghtml5.com/2011/01/03/iframes-and-iphones/

(Disclaimer, I'm not an iPhone fan, just this was a link I found on google to back my answer up)